# How to test if Rails rack-cors gem is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman, rails-api, rack-cors

I am trying to build a React - Rails API project. I added `gem 'rack-cors'` and created the `config/initializers/cors.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins "http://localhost:3001" 
      # The React part will be on port 3001 so thats way we add it
      # Change it to the production url when going on production
  
      resource "*",
        headers: :any,
        methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
    end
end
```

I would only like to allow the port `3001` since thats the port my React front-end will be served at.
Now I would like to test if this is actually working and blocking other requests.

Up until now, I have been using `Postman` to test the API (had to download it to work with `http`). I thought that because I added the filter to only a specific port, it would block the requests from `Postman` but it is still showing the data requested in the API call.

Also if I try reaching it like this on the browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
```

It is still giving the data, which should be blocked to every port except `3001`.

Why is it happening? Is there any other way to double check if it is working?
NOTE: I killed the server and restarted it again and it is still behaving the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test CORS locally, I found this repo: https://github.com/njgibbon/nicks-cors-test

Just clone it, and click on the `html` file so it opens in your browser. By default it is calling the `github API` (https://api.github.com) and fetching info from there. You can open the console and check it.
If you change it to `https://google.com` it will throw a CORS restriction.

Similarly, you can change it to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users` (in my case) and it will throw a CORS error with the config I have now.

To double-check, just go to `cors.rb` and put `origins "*"`. Restart the app server and try running again the html file. Now we won't be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Make an API call from browser (Not from URL and Not from postman). May be through ajax to test.

```
Postman does not implement the CORS restrictions
```

Comment: Thank you! @Dyaniyal Wilson. How could I do that call? I tried `curl -s http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users` from the terminal but it is still showing the data

Answer (score 1):

just solved it by adding
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
after adding the require bit it worked

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
curl -I -X OPTIONS \
  -H "Origin: https://ORIGIN.com" \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
  "https://URL_YOU_WANT_TO_TEST" 2>&1 | grep -i 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

if it returns https://ORIGIN.com , it works.